# Is there a way to track my app's search ranking on Apple App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-optimization

I want to programmatically track my app's search ranking on Apple's app store. Is there any API or website to do this, outside of the 'App Store' app on my iPhone?

Comment: There's a web API, indeed, but it's not public. You may use it but then your app can't be distributed on the AppStore (iOS or OS X).

Comment: Could you please point me towards the non-public web API?

Answer (score 68):

the following websites allow searching the iOS app store.

1. https://theappstore.org
2. http://fnd.io

Answer (score 14):

I'm not sure how the exact ranking is reflected, but Apple now provides an JSON API call that you can make.

https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/

This includes the ability to add in a callback parameter so you can even incorporate it into a web app without having to parse the results on your server.

The end API call would looks something like this:

http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=props&entity=software&country=US&callback=lkasdfj

Comment: Thanks a lot, this saved the day

Answer (score 9):

In case users are still looking for this.  Apple finally made it possible to just use the apple.com website:

https://www.apple.com/ios/app-store/  Use the magnifying glass in the top right to search the apps.

Once you find the app you want, there is a unique URL that you could use to grab information for tracking or other purposes as well.

You can't do anything other than look at the app information at this time (no way to initiate a remote install to your phone or leave a review, that has to be done on the device)

Comment: I typed "photo" in the magnifying glass bar, but it doesn't show me any photo apps.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that many keywords are reserved for the entire apple site.  If you search for a specific photo app that has a less generic name it might work, but "photo" moves you to a more global search.  If you search for "Termius" or "Clash of Clans" it will search the app store as expected

Comment: Apparently the search system will try to infer a *category* for the results between "Explore" (apps, apparently), "Accessories", "Support" and "Apple Store". On `https://www.apple.com/search/<term>` it's (currently) possible to tack on the `sel=explore` query parameter to ensure it opens the explore tab, but who knows how long that'll work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the google advance search option like

> site:itunes.apple.com/us/ "requires iOS 9 or later"

and then **scrape** the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [data.ai](https://www.data.ai/en/) formerly App Annie. The free version will give you daily and overall search ranking for your app, and will help you immensely in ASO (App store optimization)